# How to convert and check date with different format in Groovy

Tags: date, jenkins, groovy

In my groovy code, I have 2 Dates

```
def date1 = "2021-08-02T03:22:12Z"

dev date2 = new Date()
```

my goal is, if date1 is 5 days older than date2 return true.,

date2 looks like that Thu Aug 05 10:13:56 UTC 2021

but How to convert 2 dates with right date format before comparing?

any solutions?

Comment: Is the first one meant to be a String?

Comment: yes, the first one ist a string

Answer (score 0):

```
def date1 = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2021-08-02T03:22:12Z")
def date2 = new Date()
def daysDiff = date2-date1
println daysDiff
```